# How do charges in a circuit know how much work to do on a component?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons

So I'm a high school student learning physics so I don't really know much about circuits yet. Our teacher said that in a circuit, electrons don't really flow through the circuit and that there's more to it but it's more complicated to understand right now. Anyway, I was wondering how a coulomb of charge in a circuit knows how much work to do on a particular electrical component. For example, if I had a circuit with and LED that could only handle 3V and I had a 5V battery, I would have to put a resistor before the LED then how come the charges don't use up all the 5V on the resistor? Or if I have 2 LEDs in series, why doesn't all the energy get used on the first LED until there's no more energy or the LED short circuits? I've looked at similar questions on stack exchange but I didn't really understand and I've also heard of the water pipe example which didn't make much sense to me either.

Answer (score 0):

$$P=IV $$

If there is a potential difference across 2 points, with a wire inbetween with current I, this is the rate at which energy is being used [power].

Devices will have a maximum power limit,  anything above this will cause the device to potentially overheat and break,

We also know from ohms law that:

$$V=IR$$
$$\frac{V}{R} = I$$

Substituting into our power equation:

$$P= \frac{V^2}{R}$$

Let's assume for the minute that my device can only take upto 10W, before breaking and my device also has a total resistance of  $R_{0}$

We must therefore know that:

$$10 > \frac{V^2}{R_{0}}$$

$$\sqrt{10R_{0}} > V$$

If the potential across the device is over this amount, it will break.

Let's say I have battery of  $[\sqrt{10R_{0}} + 100]V$

If there are no components that lower the potential of across the device, by atleast 100V, then my device will break.

In reality, the wire that you connect it to the battery with, will have some resistance, so will lower the voltage across.

However if this is not enough,  you are correct and will need to have a resistor in order to lower the potential.

Answer (score 0):

The water analogy with water height being analogous to voltage (potential), and the resistance being related to the diameter of the pipe is a good analogy but has some limitations. I think you can probably find some good explanations on youtube or if you google around.  But if you haven’t worked with water and pipes, it might not be that intuitive….

So think about having a straw and blowing air through it. The pressure is from your lungs and you can choose the diameter of the straw you want to blow through. You can only have so much pressure and blow so hard, so the pressure is like the battery and the wide-open straw is like the wire. The pressure is like the voltage. Wide open the straw doesn’t have a lot of resistance.  If you pinch the middle of the straw, then that is your resistor. If you put a wide open straw and a pinched straw in your mouth at the same time then most of the air you blow out would go the low resistance path and less would go through the pinched straw. That would be like two resistors in parallel.  If you put two pinches in one straw, that would be like having two resistors in series.

If you measured the pressure on the side of the pinch that is closer to your mouth that would be a higher pressure, or for a resistor a higher voltage side, and on the other side of the pinch it would be the lower pressure side. So as you go across the pinch you drop the pressure, or in the case of a resistor you drop the voltage. More resistance a bigger voltage drop.  If you put your finger across the end of the straw with the pinch, and blocked the flow completely then the resistance would be infinite and you would have an open circuit, and there would be no flow, or in the case of a circuit there would be no flow of electrons. But if you had even a tiny leak around your finger, you would have some flow and have a pressure drop.

So in the water or in this case Air analogy the flow is the analogous to the flow of electrons.

When you think about using things up, you need to consider that you can not create or destroy electrons in your circuit. And unless it is something special like an electron beam or electron emitter or a spark they are not leaving the circuit.

However, the voltage (or the potential) is like potential energy, If I have a tall column of water, I have a higher pressure at the bottom than a shorter column of water. A wider column of water of the same height would have the ability to supply water longer would have more energy. Running out of breath, or water would be like depleting your battery.

So you are not using up electrons in your circuit, but you are dropping the voltage or potential across circuit elements. When you put the resistor in from of the LED, you are limiting voltage to what the LED can handle, essentially pinching the straw so the flow of electrons (current)  is limited. When you have the two LEDs in a row and the LEDS are connected correctly there is only a little voltage drop across the first LED and then there would be another little voltage drop across the second LED and if you had the resistor in front of the two LEDS it would be like the straw had three pinches, a big one for the resistor and two little pinches for the LEDS and the total resistance would be the sum of the resistance of the resistor and the resistance of the two LEDS, but importantly the flow of the electrons going though would be the same for the resistor and the same current for LED1 and the same current for LED2.

As you learn more all of this can be put into equations and as you get familiar with the equations, it can still be useful to think about analogies like this when trouble shooting.